# How do I access the originally submitted data of a Symfony form?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm working with some Symfony forms and need to access the originally submitted (untouched) data. The data accessor methods `$form->getData()`, `$form->getViewData()` and `$form->getModelData()` all give me the already transformed values, but I need the data as in the `PRE_SUBMIT` event.

I could write a listener and extract them on `PRE_SUBMIT`, but then I have to store this information anywhere and access it in my service working with the form. For now, my service sees only the passed form object and does its work with no other dependencies.

Other workarounds involve reading from the request object. Doesn't look like a smart option, because the form may be filled from other sources (like the session, it is a filter form).

Is there an "official" way to access the originally submitted data directly from the form object? If not, would it be worth a feature request? Any opinions on that?

(My usecase is a filter form, where the state is stored in and retrieved from the session. Since the form may be submitted without data coming from the request involving modes for HTML-POST, HTML-GET and JSON-POST, I don't want to just store the request data.)

Edit 2018-06-07: As requested in the comments, I provide a code example:

```
/**
 * handles the filterForm request reading POST-data or namespaced JSON payload with POST method or any standard form request
 *
 * @param FormInterface $filterForm
 * @return void
 * @throws ResponseException
 */
public function handleRequest(FormInterface $filterForm): void
{
    // reset the filter state in the session, if a reset_filter query parameter was set
    if (true === $this->request->query->getBoolean('reset_filter', false)) {
        $this->setFilterState(null, $this->request->attributes->get('_route'));
        $this->filterIsActive = true;
    }

    // handle filter submission in json context
    if ($this->request->isMethod('POST') && $this->request->attributes->get('_format') === 'json') {
        if ($this->request->get($filterForm->getName())) {
            $submitData = $this->request->get($filterForm->getName());
        }
        else {
            $postData = JsonHelper::parseAndCheckJsonPostData($this->request);
            if ($postData instanceof Response) {
                throw new ResponseException($postData);
            }
            $submitData = $postData[$filterForm->getName()] ?? null;
        }
        if (null !== $submitData) {
            dump($submitData);
            $filterForm->submit($submitData, true);
            dump($filterForm->getData());
        }
    }
    else {
        // @todo find a smooth way to get the original submitted data of a form, when it is handled by the default handleRequest()-menthod
        $submitData = null;
        $filterForm->handleRequest($this->request);
    }

    // load the filter state from the session and submit it, if it is not yet set and we are in HTML context
    if (!$filterForm->isSubmitted()
        && $this->request->attributes->get('_format') === 'html'
        && null !== $this->getFilterState($this->request->attributes->get('_route'))
    ) {
        $filterForm->submit($this->getFilterState($this->request->attributes->get('_route')));
    }

    if ($filterForm->isSubmitted()) {
        $this->filterIsActive = true;

        // return an JSON error-document, if the filter form is not valid
        if (!$filterForm->isValid() && $this->request->attributes->get('_format') === 'json') {
            throw new ResponseException(
                new JsonResponse([
                    'type' => 'error',
                    'message' => $this->translator->trans('Form.Filter.errorMessage'),
                    'filterForm' => $this->serializer->normalize($filterForm->createView()),
                ], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)
            );
        }

        // store the new filter state, if filter is active and and valid
        if ($filterForm->isValid() && null !== $submitData) {
            $this->setFilterState($submitData, $this->request->attributes->get('_route'));
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs this:

```
array:4 [▼
    "singleEntity" => "1"
    "multipleEntities" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "1"
    ]
    "dateRange" => array:2 [▼
        "left_date" => "06.06.2018"
        "right_date" => "07.06.2018"
    ]
    "submit" => true
]

array:11 [▼
    "singleEntity" => MySingleEntity {#3739 ▶}
    "facilities" => ArrayCollection {#3419 ▼
        -elements: array:1 [▼
            0 => MyMultiEntity {#3799 ▶}
        ]
    }
    "createdOrUpdatedBetween" => array:2 [▼
        "left_date" => DateTime @1528236000 {#3408 ▼
            date: 2018-06-06 00:00:00.0 Europe/Berlin (+02:00)
        }
        "right_date" => DateTime @1528322400 {#3397 ▼
            date: 2018-06-07 00:00:00.0 Europe/Berlin (+02:00)
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: If it's a filter form why do you need to transform the values? Can you explain the case in more detail please? Normally in a filter form the values are not transformed.

Comment: The forms use the LexikFormFilterBundle, where at least the Date and DateTime fields are transformed into DateTime-objects. In my case, I use Entity-filters a lot and their submitted values are transformed into their entities. Which is great since this helps a lot handling the filter-logic.

Comment: Can you provide a use case for the data that comes from the request (and you need in raw format) and what is it transformed to? Also, what do you need the raw data for? (Just asking a maybe there is a better approach rather than trying to get the raw data from the form)

Comment: I didn't want to discuss my implementation, but now you asked, I provided my code. As you can see, I store the submitted data in the session and load (and submit) it again, when the user loads the html-version of the page next time. So when the users come back, they have their last filter state. At the moment, the case in question doesn't happen in practice (filters are applied only via POST/JSON), but maybe this raises a problem in the future. So I'm looking for a final non-hacked solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have two options how to save submitted data

1) Take directly from Request

```
$submitted_data = [];
foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
    if ($request->request->has($child->getName())) {
        $submitted_data[$child->getName()] = $request->request->get($child->getName());
    }
}
```

2) use Form events

```
$submitted_data = null;
$formBuilder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use (&$submitted_data) {
    $submitted_data = $event->getData();
});
```

Comment: Both options and why they are not good options is discussed inside the question. The question is basically about getting the raw data from the form object that is passed to the handleRequest-method that should not have any other dependencies. I could do the PRE_SUBMIT-stuff and store the raw data to the request, if it does not come from there. So the handleRequest-method always gets the raw form data from the request, even if the form was filled from the user session. A bit hacky, but could be a solution.